# ARM Deployment error Document Db cannot find instance

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We are having a deployment error in working deployments since last Thursday AEST.

When we run an ARM deployment DocumentDb fails with the message:

Resource Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts 'xxx' failed with message 'Document service name 'xxx' already exists.

```
 {
     "apiVersion": "2015-04-08",
     "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
     "name": "[parameters('databaseAccountName')]",
     "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
     "properties": {
       "name": "[parameters('databaseAccountName')]",
       "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard"
     }
```

In the snippet [parameters('databaseAccountName')] = 'xxx'

We are guessing that something underlying has happened to cause this. Can you please let us know the new properties into the ARM template that we need to include for the DocumentDb instance to be found again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: We have updated our documentation to cover ARM deployment for multi-region enabled accounts. https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/documentdb-automation-resource-manager-cli/#create-multi-documentdb-account

We are in the process of enabling multi-region accoutns for all accounts. As a part of this effort, there is a change in the ARM template. A few accounts are seeing errors when using the currently published template in certain scenarios.

We will be updating our documentation very soon. In the meantime, the below template should get you going. Your old template will also start working in a couple of days.

```
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "databaseAccountName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "locationName1": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"variables": { },
"resources": [
    {
        "apiVersion": "2015-04-08",
        “kind”: “GlobalDocumentDB”,
        "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts",
        "name": "[parameters('databaseAccountName')]",
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "properties": {
            "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard",
            "locations": [
            {
                "id": "[concat(parameters('databaseAccountName'), '-', resourceGroup().location)]",
                "failoverPriority": 0,
                "locationName": "[parameters('locationName1')]"
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

Edit:

locationName1 should be in the format of the "Azure Regions" column on this page: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/

Comment: I did mark this as correct, but unfortunately we now receive this error: 'Failover priority value 0 supplied for region australiaeast is invalid

Comment: It works for me. Make sure you don't use resourceGroup().location instead of parameter locationName1. in my case we deploy to a resource group located in north europe so resourceGroup().location = 'northeurope' and locationName1 = 'North Europe'.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. This solution does work. Have a great weekend :)

Comment: When I make the suggested change I get the error "No registered resource provider found for location 'northeurope' and API version '2016-03-31' for type 'databaseAccounts'.", which is baffling as I have "apiVersion": "2015-04-08", and don't have the string "2016-03-31" anywhere in my template.